# Trying to setup break statement

Tags: java

I have this java code I created for a course.  I have tried and continue to fail implement a break statement.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class gradeAverage {

    public static void main( String[] args ){
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            int input1;
            int input2;
            int input3;

            //Calculate
            int studentAvg;

            //Prompt for first user input or break if input = q
            System.out.print( "Enter first student grade or q to quit: ");
             if {
                (input1=input.nextInt() = q)
                 break;
                else
                    input1=input.nextInt() =;
    }
            //Prompt for second user input or break if input = q
            System.out.print( "Enter second student grade or q to quit: ");
            input2=input.nextInt();

            //Prompt for third user input or break if input = q
            System.out.print( "Enter third student grade or q to quit: ");
            input3=input.nextInt();

            studentAvg=(input1+input2+input3)/3;

            System.out.printf( "The Student's grade average is %d\n" , studentAvg);

    }
}
```

Comment: Don't declare variable far far away from the place where you really need to use it. `int input2=input.nextInt();` `int input3=input.nextInt();` and `int studentAvg=(input1+input2+input3)/3;` whould be better - you don't need to scroll the code to find out wether this particular  `studentAvg` is int/lond/float or double...

Answer (score 5):

A break statement needs to be inside a loop or some sort (`for`, `while`, or `do`), you cannot break out of an `if` conditional.

If you put your code inside this:

```
while(true) {
  ...
}
```

Then your break would work fine.

Also the format of an if statement is:

```
if (condition) {
  ...
} else {

}
```

You seem to have a `if { (condition)` in your code...

Oh and `=` is an assignment of a value to a variable, `==` is an equality check, you have them mixed up.

Comment: He/She's got to fix the whole syntax of his/her `if` statement too.

Comment: I trink that `return` would be more suitable than adding some `while(true)` to let `break` break something...

Comment: and `something = something2` is not a condition :)

Comment: I am a complete noob at Java so thanks for all your input. Maybe I went about it wrong but I first created the scanner input and now trying to create the if statement and messed my self up in what I would like to accomplish. I am now trying to make the input look for the q to break or store the numeric value in int intput1, 2 or three.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your syntax of If statement is totally wrong . That needs to be corrected.

Second this is that , Break statement is used to break a loop in between. So it should be used like

while{
................
Break;
................

}

or

For(.........){

Break;
........
}

Answer (score -2):

//Assuming input is a scanner object.

```
System.out.print( "Enter first student grade or q to quit: ");
             if ((input1=input.nextline()).equalsIgnoreCase("q")) //do you want to use == or =?
                 break;

                else{
                   //do something
    }
```

This should do the trick for you. Cheers.

Comment: break what? and anyway - I bet it would not compile ;)

Comment: This doesn't compile. There isn't a bracket before the `else`.

Comment: Its only a snippet, and you do not need a bracket before the else. the if is implicitly complete because there is only 1 statement under it.

I am not sure what condition is being checked though. Only thing is that, the earlier code did not work because of misplacement of curly braces.

Comment: This will not compile.  The if condition is not a condition, the else assignment sends with "=;".  Seriously?

Comment: @user2180705 *the if is implicitly complete...* [Oh really?](http://i.stack.imgur.com/lDDFz.png)

Comment: Thanks for your help so far. I will try this out in the morning.